# Adding attributes to cq5 form using FormsHelper

Tags: aem, formhelper

I'm trying to add an attribute to the form tag of a cq5 form. I noticed that the output is generated using

```
FormsHelper.startForm(slingRequest, new JspSlingHttpServletResponseWrapper(pageContext));
```

I was curious how I can either:

1. alter the request so that the formHelper prints the form w/ the attributes I need
2. Hook into the actual print out to include the attributes I need.

Any help or direction would be good.

note:
I've already checkout out the javadoc for formshelper, done some searching via goolgle, and dev.day.com including the dev.day.com doc on developing forms.

thank you

Comment: Could you describe what are the attributes you'd like to add?

Answer (score 0):

API doesn't allow you to add any attributes to this tag. You can only specify desired CSS classes adding `css` property to the form component. Of course, you can also create [component sling filter](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/filters.html) and [response wrapper](http://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling5/org/apache/sling/api/wrappers/SlingHttpServletResponseWrapper.html) to rewrite created form, but it seems to be an overkill. I think better solution is using JS to add attributes client-side.